# My 8GB Toshiba USB drive became 4mb in size how can i restore it?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My 8gb USB drive just became 4mb. I already tried the diskpart method, bootice, HP USB Storage Format. But still the capacity still the same. Is there other way?

Comment: Also related: [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8 GB size back?](//superuser.com/q/382242/354511), [Flash disk capacity turns from 32 GB to 4 MB](//superuser.com/q/937410/354511), [USB drive not showing full size](//superuser.com/q/88509/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive shows as 16 MB & is unusable](/q/50207/354511), [1 GB space left after formatting a 16 GB flash drive?](/q/339489/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive turned to 1 GB after writing an ISO image onto it](/q/759602/354511), and [Toshiba pen drive shows 4 MB instead of 8 GB; what could have happened to it?](/q/927680/354511)

Answer (score 2):

Plug your pen-drive into the computer.
Go to Run->cmd.
type "diskpart".
A new window will pop up.
In the Diskpart window, type "select disk 1" and press enter.
Now type "clean" and press enter.
Now type "create partition primary" and hit enter.
You are done!!! :)
Goto My computer and format your disk and you'll have the space. :)

Comment: OP states tried diskpart already and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems accidentally you have deleted partition in your removable disk. Create a partition in order to utilize the full capacity.

you will not be able to create a partition in windows so use software [ease us partition master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/) 
home version. it is free.

Otherwise you can Create new partition by running **gparted** command using **Ubuntu live CD**.and I think it is the best option.
[Check this link](http://bestthings4u.blogspot.in/2014/03/make-partition-in-pendrive.html)
it will help you.